# How to persist output of window() function in JDBC with Spark SQL DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When the following snippet executes:

```
...
stream
      .map(_.value())
      .flatMap(MyParser.parse(_))
      .foreachRDD(rdd => {
        val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(rdd.sparkContext.getConf).getOrCreate()
        import spark.implicits._

        val dataFrame = rdd.toDF();
        val countsDf = dataFrame.groupBy($"action", window($"time", "1 hour")).count()
        val query = countsDf.write.mode("append").jdbc(url, "stats_table", prop)
      })
....
```

This error happens: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get JDBC type for struct<start:timestamp,end:timestamp>`

How would one go about saving the output of `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.window()` function to a MySQL DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem using SPARK SQL:

```
val query3 = dataFrame
  .groupBy(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.window($"timeStamp", "10 minutes"), $"data")
  .count()
  .writeStream
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Complete())
  .options(prop)
  .option("checkpointLocation", "file:///tmp/spark-checkpoint1")
  .option("table", "temp")
  .format("com.here.olympus.jdbc.sink.OlympusDBSinkProvider")
  .start
```

And I solved by adding a *user defined function*

```
val toString = udf{(window:GenericRowWithSchema) => window.mkString("-")}
```

For me String works, but you can change the function according to your needs, you can even have two functions to return start and end separately.

My query changed to:

```
val query3 = dataFrame
  .groupBy(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.window($"timeStamp", "10 minutes"), $"data")
  .count()
  .withColumn("window",toString($"window"))
  .writeStream
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Complete())
  .options(prop)
  .option("checkpointLocation", "file:///tmp/spark-checkpoint1")
  .option("table", "temp")
  .format("com.here.olympus.jdbc.sink.OlympusDBSinkProvider")
  .start
```